# Does $b_n$ diverge or converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $a_n$ is a divergent sequence . Does $b_n = n \times a_n$ diverge or converge ? Obviously , There is no general rule for the limit of multiplication divergent sequences but I can't find a counterexample that shows $b_n$ is convergent .

Comment: For $na_n$ being convergent it's necessary  that $a_n$ converges to $0$, otherwise $na_n$ diverges…. So if $a_n$ diverges so does $b_n$

Comment: @Gono Can you prove that ?

Comment: Done in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $b_n$ converges to $b$, hence

$$\begin{align*}&\forall\varepsilon > 0\;\exists N\;\forall n\ge N\;\; |b_n - b| < \varepsilon \\ \iff &\forall\varepsilon > 0\;\exists N\;\forall n\ge N\;\; |na_n - b| < \varepsilon \\ \iff &\forall\varepsilon > 0\;\exists N\;\forall n\ge N\;\; |a_n - \frac{b}{n}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{n}\end{align*}$$

So especially it holds $$\forall\varepsilon > 0\;\exists N\;\forall n\ge N\;\; |a_n - \frac{b}{n}| < \varepsilon$$ because $\frac{\varepsilon}{n} \le \varepsilon$

But that means $$a_n - \frac{b}{n} \to 0$$ what proves $a_n \to 0$

So it holds: $b_n$ converges implies $a_n$ converges to $0$.

Contraposition: $a_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ implies $b_n$ does not converge

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n a_n \to \ell \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $b_n = 1/n$. Then $a_n = (n a_n) b_n \to \ell \cdot 0 = 0$.

Therefore if $a_n$ diverges, so must $n a_n$.